# css: link group is placed outside the containing div

Tags: css

In the following code from: http://6.470.scripts.mit.edu/css_exercises/exercise5.html

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper1 {
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eeeeee;
}
.wrapper2 {
    clear: left;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #111111;
}
.p1 {
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 70px;
}
.p2 {
    font-size: 50px;
}
.link-gr {
    list-type: none;
}
.link-gr li{
    float: left;
}
.link-gr li a{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="wrapper2">
<p class="p1">MIT 6.470</p>
<p class="p2">Learn Web Programming this IAP</p>
<ul class="link-gr">
<li><a href="">Comprehensive Curriculum</a></li>
<li><a href="">Insightful Guest Lectures</a></li>
<li><a href="">Interaction with Sponsors</a></li>
<li><a href="">$30,000+ in Total Prizes</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
Copyright © 2012 MIT 6.470
</div>
</body>
```

the ul.link-gr links are falling outside the div. I mean everything excluding the links are wrapped inside div.wrapper2 with border and black-ish background but the links are placed outside the box (like outcast-ed). This is very strange. Some explanation from your side will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This looks fine on my screen. The links are showing up in the grey box.

Comment: The HTML in the link you posted is not the same as the HTML you posted in your question.

Comment: Yes I know. I posted the link to show how it should look but is not happening.

Comment: In the original site, they used overflow:auto; and it solved the problem.

Comment: but if I use overflow: hidden then it works too. Not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I would think this is a `float` problem: your code contains

```
.link-gr li{
    float: left;
}
```

The problem is that its container is not `float: left`, which means that the list items are free to go anywhere. Try adding `float: left` to the `.link-gr` as well:

```
.link-gr{
    float: left;
}
```

This may solve the problem. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abZHK/1/

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail so I can tackle it? (I must have misunderstood it because the Fiddle works fine)

Comment: The problem is that the links such as "Comprehensive Curriculum" is outside the div with black background which is supposed to be the container.

Comment: Remove all the `float` attributes, then change the `display`s of various elements. See my updated Fiddle for code: http://jsfiddle.net/abZHK/2/

Answer (score 0):

Ah floats...

## Explanations

See this old article from P.I.E: [Clearing floats](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) (IE/Win is IE version 6 there)

## Solution

Apply this modern **[clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)** (on parent of the non-contained floats)